# Differentiate and Highlight the difference between the two Fields

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have an ntext column in the database in which I am storing the Html Content or the text provided by the User. I want to implement history on the column and for this I am storing the content after and before the edit operation.

I want to find the Difference between the two values in the column and highlight the difference.

Any Idea how to do this?

My english is not good so please feel free to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Something like this?](http://www.mathertel.de/Diff/default.aspx), [or this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/DiffAlgorithmCS.aspx) would be a useful starting point- both by the same guy.

Comment: I have tried this but I am really not able to understand how it works and what is the best way to use it.Any example of how this can be implemented would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Actually cvs saves exactly diff format on the repository, so if you will look at server side file, yo will see something like (i don't going show exact format, try see idea only)

```
==version ##==
[+] bla-bla
[-] bla-bla
base text....
```

There are huge number of free libraries to generate this.